# Sequelize - order by associations conditionally

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a model, say Base which has one Details1 model or has one Details2 model depending on the value of a field "type" (which says either details1 or details2).

Both `Details1` and `Details2` have a field "orderField".

Is there a way to order rows of the Base model by either Details1.orderField or Details2.orderField depending on whether Base.type = details1 or details2 ?

I have tried looking up the `sequelize` docs relating to ordering: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/querying.html#ordering

I have tried this:

```js
Base.findAll(
{
  include: [
     { model: Details1 },
     { model: Details2 }
  ],
  order: [
     [
       { model: Details1, as: 'Details1' }, 'orderField', 'DESC'
     ],[
       { model: Details2, as: 'Details2' }, 'orderField', 'DESC'
     ]
  ]
});
```

The above code, however, orders rows of Base models by Details1.orderField separately and by Details2.orderField separately.

For instance, if I had the following data:

```
{type: details1, Details1: {orderField: 2}}
{type: details2, Details2: {orderField: 1}}
{type: details2, Details2: {orderField: 5}}
{type: details1, Details1: {orderField: 4}}
{type: details2, Details2: {orderField: 3}}
```

Then the expected order is:

```
{type: details2, Details2: {orderField: 5}}
{type: details1, Details1: {orderField: 4}}
{type: details2, Details2: {orderField: 3}}
{type: details1, Details1: {orderField: 2}}
{type: details2, Details2: {orderField: 1}}
```

However, I am getting the output as:

```
{type: details1, Details1: {orderField: 4}}
{type: details1, Details1: {orderField: 2}}
{type: details2, Details2: {orderField: 5}}
{type: details2, Details2: {orderField: 3}}
{type: details2, Details2: {orderField: 1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try: use a CASE statement to derive a single field for sorting.

```
   order: [
   [Sequelize.literal("case when details1.orderField not null then details1.orderField else details2.orderField end")]
   ]
```

You might have to play around with the table aliases to make this work.